# How to prevent a base64 encoding from hanging the browser?

Tags: javascript, android, base64

At my 9-to-5 we regularly Base64 images when we work with image uploads for forms/apps etc for it's 'simplicity' in transmitting over AJAX and some other minor reasons.

- However we regularly have issues when using this method with 'old'
  Android devices.
- The browser sometimes hangs - *displays an available memory error
  message* and just restarts. Other times it just restarts without
  popping any alerts.
- This happens only on large images and on old Android devices that
  have a lot of apps running etc, etc.

One solution is to reduce the size of the image before DataUrl'ing the whole thing - but sometimes this is not enough - we need the image to be of a relative size, e.g we can't use a pinhead size of an image.

> How can we prevent the browser from hanging over this?

*I have thought of a solution where I would use WebWorkers to asynchronously encode it in the background - but I am thinking what difference would that make? The UI might not freeze but memory is being used anyway.*

> Are there any other possible solutions?

***Note***: We are targeting only Android 4.1+ and iOS6+

Anyway,

This is the function we currently use for resizing and encoding to Base64.

---

```
function resizeCanvasImage(img, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
        var imgWidth = img.width, 
            imgHeight = img.height;

        var ratio = 1, ratio1 = 1, ratio2 = 1;
        ratio1 = maxWidth / imgWidth;
        ratio2 = maxHeight / imgHeight;

        // Use the smallest ratio that the image best fit into the maxWidth x maxHeight box.
        if (ratio1 < ratio2) {
            ratio = ratio1;
        }
        else {
            ratio = ratio2;
        }
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas");
        var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext("2d");
        var canvasCopy2 = document.createElement("canvas");
        var copyContext2 = canvasCopy2.getContext("2d");
        canvasCopy.width = imgWidth;
        canvasCopy.height = imgHeight;  
        copyContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // init
        canvasCopy2.width = imgWidth;
        canvasCopy2.height = imgHeight;        
        copyContext2.drawImage(canvasCopy, 0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height, 0, 0, canvasCopy2.width, canvasCopy2.height);

        var rounds = 2;
        var roundRatio = ratio * rounds;
        for (var i = 1; i <= rounds; i++) {


            // tmp
            canvasCopy.width = imgWidth * roundRatio / i;
            canvasCopy.height = imgHeight * roundRatio / i;

            copyContext.drawImage(canvasCopy2, 0, 0, canvasCopy2.width, canvasCopy2.height, 0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height);

            // copy back
            canvasCopy2.width = imgWidth * roundRatio / i;
            canvasCopy2.height = imgHeight * roundRatio / i;
            copyContext2.drawImage(canvasCopy, 0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height, 0, 0, canvasCopy2.width, canvasCopy2.height);

        } // end for


        // return Base64 string of the downscaled image
        canvas.width = imgWidth * roundRatio / rounds;
        canvas.height = imgHeight * roundRatio / rounds;
        canvasContext.drawImage(canvasCopy2, 0, 0, canvasCopy2.width, canvasCopy2.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

        return dataURL;

    }
```

Comment: According to [this post](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/), base64'ing a picture generates a file 33% bigger than the original. I realize it's simpler to use base64, but I think that you'll find to solve this problem, you *can't* use base64.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm interested only for B64 encoding at this moment - If there really are no practical solutions, I'll investigate the alternative methods